# Curious about understanding fog gem document

Tags: ruby, rubygems

While updating my gems I found this one of the line.

I did search a lot but I couldn't find anything informative,
and I really want to understand what this document has to do with the gem fog.

```
Parsing documentation for fog-serverlove-0.1.2
Installing ri documentation for fog-serverlove-0.1.2
Installing darkfish documentation for fog-serverlove-0.1.2
```

Comment: run rdoc cli helper and see output `ri fog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fog` gem provides an interface to several cloud services, one of which is [Serverlove](http://www.serverlove.com/). For modularity and organization, the top-level gem depends on many other gems named `fog-*`, for example [`fog-serverlove`](https://github.com/fog/fog-serverlove). When you install a gem, you also install all of that gem's dependencies, which is why you see `fog-serverlove` in the update output.

Take a look at [`fog.gemspec`](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/v1.36.0/fog.gemspec#L67) to see `fog-serverlove` and the rest of the gems `fog` depends on.

Comment: Wow Thank you so much. I am so amazed of how all of this just connected together.